# How can I change a process running inside an emacs *shell* buffer to background

Tags: shell, emacs, ctrl

Normally I would use `C-z` to accomplish this but this will cause emacs itself to go into the background.

Say I have a long program running inside the *shell* buffer of emacs (and I stupidly forgot to place the `&` at the end of the command), then is there a way to make that process go into the background and get back to the command prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `shell` command, you can propagate <kbd>C-z</kbd> to it through <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-z</kbd>.

Comment: I did do searching first but now I realize that this is well explained in the emacs manual for shell mode: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Mode.html